# I fail to understand the rules of using StringBuffer, append, conversions

Tags: java, loops, char, type-conversion, stringbuffer

I was wondering if anyone could help me figuring out why my code doesn't do what I expect it to do. The idea was to count the same following letters in a `StringBuffer` and transform it into something like this `AABBC => 2A2B1C`. Now my program doesn't do that and it probably has to do with my poor usage of these newly-learned concepts. Do I have to convert `marker` into a `char` for it to print it out? Or is the structure of my code inherently wrong? I'm also not sure what I can do with `StringBuffer`s and what not.

```
package package1;

public class Strings {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int marker = 1;
        StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("AAAA");
        for(int i = 0; i<=s.length(); i++){
            while(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)){
                marker++;
            }
            i += marker;
            s2.append(marker);
            s2.append(s.charAt(i));
            marker = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(s2); // It simply prints out nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: Do not change the `i` inside your loop. it leads to such problems

Answer (score 0):

You have an [off-by-one-error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) bug in your code.

You are counting how many times you've seen a char starting from `1` but string indexes start from zero and you are mixing up the two later when you are assigning `marker` to `i` using `getCharAt(i)` is off by one (in this case it tries to get the char at index 4 which is passed the end of the string).

An Easy way to fix it is to have your count (`marker`) start at `0` too and only increase by one what you are appending to the string:

```
package package1;

public class Strings {
  public static void main(String[]args){
    int marker = 0; // changing this to 0
    StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("AAAA");
    for(int i = 0; i<=s.length(); i++){
        while(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)){
            marker++;
        }
        i += marker;
        s2.append(marker + 1); // print out the count plus one because we are counting from zero
        s2.append(s.charAt(i));
        marker = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(s2); // It simply prints out nothing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while-loop never finishes.

If `s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)` is true, the marker gets increased. But because `i` stays the same the condition of your while-loop stays the same, so it runs for ever.

There are some more bugs in your code (like `i <= s.length()` and try to access s.charAt(i+1) will lead to IndexOutOfBoundsException) but you will find them.